# ADT/Eclipse bug?

Tags: android

I encountered a problem that is really annoying. I made a class file wherein the contents are the same as the demo file on the net. I copy-pasted it, renamed it, and changed the package file. Now, the problem is that whenever, suppose I do these:
`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenSlide.class);
startActivity(intent);`

`ScreenSlide.class` is the one I'm referring to. It gives me a NoClassDefFoundError. I really don't know how to fix it. I tried cleaning the project but still that problem appears. The strange thing is that I tried my project, together with the libraries I imported, deployed in another pc and guess what? There's no error! It's really frustrating. Please help me :(

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String artist = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                artist = artist.replace(' ', '+');
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenSlide.class);
                //intent.putExtra("artist", artist);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fmpdroid.lastfmartists"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.fmpdroid.lastfmartists.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.fmpdroid.lastfmartists.Second"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.fmpdroid.lastfmartists.ScreenSlide"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.fmpdroid.lastfmartists.ScreenSlidePageFragment"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you updated manifest file? Please post your code.

Comment: Are you using any external jar file?

Comment: Is your `ScreenSlide` class fragment ? @user3062224

Comment: @user3062224 Is your `ScreenSlidePageFragment` is `Fragment` ? If its Fragment then remove it from your manifest file.

Comment: Yes I do. Strangely, the problem is already fixed. I checked the jar file in Order and Export tab and cleaned the project. Anyways, thank you so much for entertaining me. Looking forward to hear from you again :)

Answer (score 0):

After you compile your code, you end up with `.class` files for each class in your program. These binary files are the bytecode that Java interprets to execute your program. The `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that the classloader, which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the `.class` file for the class that you're trying to use. It probably indicates that you haven't set the classpath option when executing your code. [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) explains how to set the classpath when you execute.